About the contractability
Let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^3$ be the surface defined by the equation $xy-zw=0$, and consider the curve $E \subset X$ defined by the equation $x=z=0$.

Question. Can $E$ be contracted to a point?


No. $E$ is a line in one of the two rulings of $X$ so it satisfies $E^2=0$, but if $X \rightarrow Y$ is a contraction to another surface then all contracted curves must have negative self-intersection.

Could you tell me why $E^2=0$ when $E$ is one of the two rulings?
I would like to know more about intersection theory.

This is because for example there is an isomorphism $X \cong \mathbf P^1 \times \mathbf P^1$ which takes the ruling to one of the $\mathbf P^1$-fibres. It is clear that one can move such a fibre to a curve that is disjoint, hence $E^2=0$.

Artin's contractibility criterion [1] implies that a necessary and sufficient condition to contract an irreducible curve $E$ on a surface $X$ is that $E^2 <0 $. In general, the contraction will give rise to a surface $Y$ with an isolated singular point.
Castelnuovo's contractibility criterion [2, Chapter V] ensures that $Y$ is smooth if and only if $E$ is an exceptional curve of the first kind, namely,
$E \simeq \mathbb{P}^1$ and $E^2=-1$.
In your case, we have a smooth quadric surface in $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ and $E$ is a line in one of the rulings. Since $E^2=0$, is it not possible to contract $E$.
An intuitive way to see the impossibility of the contraction is to observe that all the curves in the ruling $|E|$ are linearly equivalent, hence numerical equivalent, so the contraction of $E$ would automatically contract all the lines in the ruling, and the image cannot be a surface anymore.
References.
[1] M. Artin: Some numerical criteria for contractability of curves on algebraic surfaces, Amer. J. Math. 84 (1962) pp. 485–496.
[2] A. Beauville: Complex algebraic surfaces, Cambridge University Press 1996.

Thanks. This is exactly what I would like to know.
But I cannot understand why $E^2=0$ when $E$ is a one of the ruling.
If possible, I would like to know two things.

A "Direct way" of calculating $E^2$.
The reason why $E^2=0$ if $E$ is a one of the rulings.(Are there any related theorem?)

(*I'm a begginer of birational geometry)

Take another curve $E'$ in the same ruling of $E$. Since $E$ and $E'$ are linearly equivalent and disjoint effective divisors, by the properties of the intersection product we get
$$E^2 = E E' =0$$

Another way is to note that $E+F$ is a singular hyperplane section of the quadric (here $F$ is a line in the other ruling). Thus, since $EF=1$,
$$2=\deg X =(E+F)^2 =E^2+F^2+2EF = E^2+F^2+2$$
But there is an automorphism of $X$ carrying $E$ into $F$, so we must have $E^2=F^2$ and so the only possibility is $E^2=F^2=0$.

Thanks.
Why is  $(E+F)^2=\deg X$?

If $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ is a surface and $H\subset X$ is a hyperplane section, then $H^2= \deg X$. This is a straightforward consequence of Bezout Theorem.
